# Send message to aura components from lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, pubsublwc, lightning-message-service

I have a requirement to send messages from LWC component to an Aura component. The component exist on the page independently, i.e LWC is not embedded in an aura component. The components are in a lightning community and the aura component is a part of page header and lwc component is placed in one of the detail page.

Is it possible through pubsub?

Note : I'm aware that the lightning message service is going to come in future release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) in GA seems to be a promising feature for this approach.

However, if you want to roll your own then [pubsub](https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub/tree/master/force-app) repo has a simple library. Note that [pubsub](https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub) library falls under no support agreement with Salesforce.

Comment: All the code links in this answer are now dead.

Comment: @RobBaillie Fixed the repo link!